# Por que Drag-and-Drop para programação é pouco usado?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, drag-n-drop

Atualmente existem diversas aplicações *Open Source*, inclusive projetos brasileiros. Entretanto o que percebo é que é pouco utilizada a função de *Drag-and-Drop* que as **IDE**s disponibilizam.

Noto que muitos projetos são feitos utilizando o **Netbeans**, por exemplo, entretanto a interface do usuário foi montada em sua totalidade pelos programadores sem a utilização do *Drag-and-Drop* (é possível perceber pela estrutura das pastas entre outras coisas).

Pelo meu conhecimento apenas a linguagem **Object Pascal** que boa parte das aplicações é feita aproveitando as ferramentas disponíveis, no caso o [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/br).

O que eu gostaria de saber é porque isso ocorre, se é devido a deixar a aplicação mais rápida, menos suscetível a erros, ou se é por algum motivo.

Comment: Será que as respostas não se baseiam em opiniões? Eu por exemplo tenho minha opinião do porquê não costumo usar a interface gráfica para desenhar as telas no *Android*. Já no *iOS* eu utilizo muito.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues acredito que não porque quero saber se a aplicação fica mais pesada por exemplo.

Comment: Não creio que exista uma resposta de valor para um contexto amplo. Neste projeto devem ter desenhado as telas escrevendo código simplesmente porque o Swing (e junto com ele o *drag-and-drop* do Netbeans) é péssimo, uma das piores bestas já concebidas, e o único jeito de conseguir um resultado mais ou menos aceitável é esquecendo o *drag-and-drop* e fazendo tudo via código mesmo. Já Delphi e Visual Studio oferecem uma facilidade incrível de *drag-and-drop*, então todo mundo que usa estas IDEs desenha as telas preferencialmente usando o mouse. ***Drag-and-drop* é na verdade muito utilizado.**

Comment: Quanto a aplicação ficar mais pesada usando um ou outro, em Delphi, .Net e Java, a resposta é **não**. Não tem nenhuma diferença arrastar os controles pro formulário em vez de adicioná-los em runtime, desde que ao escrever código você utilize as técnicas recomendadas por cada plataforma.

Comment: Como no exemplo do Java Android, no eclipse é muito fraco o *drag-and-drop*. Já no Android Studio utilizo bastante porque dá uma ajuda preciosa.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A sua questão é um pouco ampla no sentido de que *drag-and-drop* pode significar muita coisa no contexto de desenvolvimento de sistemas.

Pra mim, por exemplo, o que vem a mente em primeiríssimo lugar é *o padrão de interação* em que o usuário precisa clicar com o ponteiro do mouse para selecionar algum objeto, manter o botão do mouse pressionado para "segurar" tal objeto e "arrastá-lo" para algum outro local de interesse (o tal *drag*), e então soltar o botão do mouse para deixar o objeto "cair" no novo local (o tal *drop*). Mas a sua pergunta também pode ser interpretada como por que as ferramentas e linguagens de programação (especificamente na construção de interfaces gráficas) usam pouco esse recurso por meio da construção mais [WYSIWYG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), em que o programador constrói a interface gráfica literalmente desenhando-a ao invés de programando com comandos textuais.

Eu acho que a sua intenção original com a pergunta é mais no sentido da segunda interpretação, mas isso está pouco claro. Seria bacana melhorar a questão. De todas as formas, eu ainda acho que a pergunta tem potencial para conteúdo útil segundo as duas interpretações, então vou tentar fornecer uma resposta.

### 1. O Padrão de Interação *Drag-and-Drop*

Em verdade o padrão de interação *drag-and-drop* é amplamente utilizado, simplesmente porque faz muito sentido na *metáfora de mesa de trabalho* (*desktop*) que a maior parte dos sistemas operacionais modernos utiliza. De fato, faz tanto sentido que essa é a segunda principal interação em praticamente qualquer aplicativo móvel (a primeira, obviamente, é o clique/toque). Esse tipo de interação com as mãos (ou o equivalente, considerando-se o mouse quase como um "avatar da sua mão"), é muito natural [a ponto de bebês tentarem usar revistas da mesma forma como usam tablets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXV-yaFmQNk). Assim, num sistema computacional, se a metáfora é de um livro ou revista você usa o dedo para "arrastar" as páginas; se é de um jogo físico, você usa o dedo para "chutar" uma bolinha; e por ai vai. Todas podem ser consideradas variações desse tipo de interação originalmente utilizado com o ponteiro do mouse.

É claro que podem haver problemas dependendo da construção da interface, especialmente quando os elementos que permitem esse tipo de interação *não deixam essa opção clara* para o usuário (sugiro ler [o item *3. No Perceived Affordance* deste ótimo artigo](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-application-design-mistakes/)). É por isso que em PCs é comum utilizar aquele ponteiro do mouse que simula uma mão aberta e fechada (esta última, literalmente "carregando" algo) para indicar que algo pode ser carregado/está sendo carregado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Fonte da imagem: http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=156119834&language=pt</sub>

### 2. O uso na Programação e Construção de Interfaces

Também não me parece que esse tipo de interação é pouco usado em programação. Como colegas citaram em comentários, ferramentas proprietárias como o Delphi e o Visual Studio têm recursos muito bons nesse sentido. Algumas outras talvez deixem a desejar. O Qt Designer, por exemplo, que eu uso frequentemente, permite apenas desenhar a interface (arrastando os componentes e definido suas propriedades em diálogos apropriados) com coisas mais básicas: criar barras de ferramentas, adicionar botões, menus, textos, organizar *layouts*, etc. Porém, quando eu precisei colocar uma barra de ferramentas em uma janela encaixável (*dock area*) tive que fazer manualmente, pois a ferramenta simplesmente não permite. Creio que deve se passar de forma bem similar com o Netbeans, por exemplo (não sei, não uso faz muito tempo).

Entretanto, cabe notar que o objetivo dessas ferramentas é justamente o apoio ao desenvolvimento de software. Como são ferramentas usadas por programadores, eventualmente torna-se tão mais fácil e trivial simplesmente programar textualmente a construção da interface gráfica do que desenhá-la, a ponto de fazer parecer que esse recurso é pouco usado.

> **ADENDO**: Nem sempre foi assim. Em um passado *bastante recente*, em que
>   não existiam (ou não se utilizavam) padrões de construção de
>   interfaces gráficas chamados *[Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)*, os programadores
>   precisavam *literlamente* descrever no texto da programação as
>   coordenadas de tela onde os componentes deveriam ser posicionados. Por
>   exemplo, o código em Advpl abaixo, [reproduzido do blog siga0984](https://siga0984.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/interface-visual-do-advpl-parte-01/), faz exatamente isso (e o [@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) vai lembrar dessa herança do [FiveWin](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fivewin)! hehehe):
>
> ```
> #include 'protheus.ch'
> User Function APPINT01()
> Local oDlg
> Local oBtn1, oSay1
>
> DEFINE DIALOG oDlg TITLE "Exemplo" FROM 0,0 TO 150,300 COLOR CLR_BLACK,CLR_WHITE PIXEL
> @ 25,05 SAY oSay1 PROMPT "Apenas uma mensagem" SIZE 60,12 OF oDlg PIXEL 
>
> @ 50,05 BUTTON oBtn1 PROMPT 'Sair' ACTION ( oDlg:End() ) SIZE 40, 013 OF oDlg PIXEL
> ACTIVATE DIALOG oDlg CENTER
> Return
> ```
>
> Deve ser fácil imaginar que, nessas condições, uma ferramenta de construção visual de 
>   interfaces seria muitíssimo bem-vinda (por mais básica que fosse).

Eu digo que apenas "parece" que esse recurso é pouco usado porque o meu entendimento é que ele existe em muitas das ferramentas que utilizamos, só que geralmente como forma de apoio na construção das interfaces gráficas. Usuários menos experientes com uma ferramenta/linguagem muito provavelmente fazem um grande uso desses recursos, talvez diminuindo a dependência dele conforme se tornam mais experientes. Você provavelmente é mais experiente com as linguagens/ferramentas que usa, e simplesmente não sente muita falta do recurso.

Esse não é o caso da maior parte dos usuários (estou usando o termo de forma geral, dado que nós programadores somos usuários de ferramentas de desenvolvimento). Na realidade, me parece que há *uma forte tendência* a nos afastarmos cada vez mais da entrada de texto como forma principal de construção de roteiros, definição de comportamentos e até mesmo da programação pura (seja pra trabalho, lazer ou educação). A intenção claramente é tornar a tarefa mais fácil para um público mais amplo. Há inúmeros exemplos dessa tendência, dentre os quais eu acho que vale citar:

- **Fungus na Unity 3D**. A Unity 3D é uma ferramenta para a programação de jogos que já facilita um bocado para os desenvolvedores. Ainda assim, é necessário construir código (utilizando C# ou Javascript). Um *add-on* bastante popular chamado [Fungus](http://fungusgames.com/) permite programar o fluxo de narrativas de forma gráfica e visual. Especialmente para programar narrativas (sequências de diálogos) faz muito mais sentido ter um fluxo gráfico do que um bloco de texto de código, e é dai que vem a popularidade dessa ferramenta.
- **Nodes no Blender**. O Blender é um software para modelagem 3D open source e muito completo. A construção de texturas e a ordem de renderização de objetos, por exemplo, são processos complicados que costumavam ser executados/automatizados por sequências de ações em várias janelas de propriedades (difíceis de memorizar, há de se dizer!) ou por código Python (geralmente não acessível ao público-alvo dessa ferramenta). Um recurso existente chamado Nodes permite configurar essas ações por meio de [um grafo de nós](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/11/05/introduction-node-groups-blender/) com propriedades e plugues de entrada e saída, de uma maneira muito mais fácil para o público geral.
- **Scratch**. O Scratch é um [projeto do MIT](http://scratch.mit.edu/) para, essencialmente, facilitar o aprendizado de programação. Nele o fluxo lógico é construído da mesma forma que se faz com qualquer algoritmo na abordagem estruturada (instruções de controle de fluxo, repetições, etc). Porém, isso é feito usando blocos visuais que são - olhe só - arrastados e combinados com o ponteiro do mouse! :) Essa interface ficou tão famosa que foi usada em várias ferramentas, entre elas o [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/) (um motor para a construção de jogos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Exemplo de um pedaço de programa (um evento, em um objeto), "escrito" no Scratch.</sub>

Comment: FiveWin é moderna, eu lembro do GetSys :) Pior, quando o GET nem era com GetSys :D E pra variar você deu uma resposta matadora, salvando a pergunta.

Comment: @bigown É que eu tô em busca da medalha "Salvador de Perguntas". :)

Comment: "a ponto de bebés tentarem usar revistas da mesma forma como usam tablets" As vezes tenho a ideia que quanto mais tecnologia mais as pessoas vão ficar *burras*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Por outro lado, isso demonstra o quão fantástico é o cérebro humano. Interações que são muito naturais para a fisiologia humana são facilmente aprendidas, e dai pra frente nós só tentamos reutilizar nossas próprias experiências para entender o mundo e prosseguir interagindo com as "novidades" nele (mesmo que sejam algo batido, como revistas). :)

Comment: Isso também é verdade. Mas tenho vindo a deparar-me com miúdos que sabem mexer em tecnologia quase melhor que eu, mas depois não sabem fazer 1+1.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, eu sei. É o mesmo padrão de quem praticamente esquece de como escrever corretamente certas palavras, já que o Google corrige durante as pesquisas. Mas há pesquisadores que argumentam que isso não é necessariamente um problema, já que a capacidade cognitiva está sendo liberada para o treinamento de outras habilidades. Com certeza dá uma boa discussão. hehehehe

Comment: Sim é verdade, mas ficamos mais dependentes da tecnologia. Eu não acho nada bom. Daria umas boas horas de debate sem grandes conclusões :D

Comment: Eu consideraria mais um aspecto nessa resposta que é versionamento de código-fonte. Quando você utiliza drag and drop, as IDE's geralmente modificam trechos de código ou arquivos que guardam o posicionamento, de forma muito confusa e que pode confundir times maiores que trabalham em conjunto. Um bom exemplo disso são os códigos gerados pelo Visual Studio nos InitializeComponent() dos formulários. Se dois desenvolvedores arrastam coisas parecidas e que conflitam, o merge pode ser bem confuso.

Comment: Pra mim o principal aspecto ainda é que quando você utiliza drag and drop, as IDE's mudam coisas não necessariamente óbvias que podem levar o teu código a ter comportamento inesperado.

Comment: @EricLemes Você tem certa razão sobre o *merge*, especialmente quando o que é gerado não é código. Mas eu não concordo que os IDE's mudam coisas que podem gerar comportamento inesperado. Pelo contrário, geralmente é muito mais óbvio para o usuáro o que está sendo feito via IDE. Além disso, como o tipo de coisas que se pode fazer via IDE é bem mais limitado do que o que se pode fazer via código, me parece que a chance de ocorrer "transgressões" é de fato bem menor quando se faz tudo pelo *drag-n-drop* do IDE.

Comment: @EricLemes De todas as formas, mesmo que tudo isso fosse verdade, talvez fosse uma razão pela qual grandes equipes não utilizariam o recurso. Não tornaria necessariamente uma verdade geral. Mas como a resposta pra pergunta é mesmo difícil, a sua colaboração foi bem colocada. Obrigado. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, um exemplo (bizarro) de comportamento inesperado: Criar algo com ASP.NET WebForms e arrastar um componente. O que está sendo feito por debaixo dos panos? Posicionamento com CSS? Posicionamento absoluto? Existe div, parágrafo, etc., na página? Em resumo, eu não tenho a menor idéia de como a IDE vai lidar com aquilo e pior ainda, as implicações da decisão da IDE em estilo, etc...

Comment: @LuizVieira concordo. Não existe resposta absoluta para essa questão. Os argumentos a favor serão: produtividade. Os argumentos contrários: falta de controle. Ambos argumentos não são tão fortes e podem tocar questões de preferência pessoal.

Comment: @EricLemes Justamente meu ponto. Você não tem a menor ideia, mas isso não faz do comportamento inesperado. Pelo contrário, ele é tão esperado quanto foi planejado pelo desenvolvedor da ferramenta. Por isso que eu digo, vc tem razão que isso torna o merge um pouco mais difícil (porque pra fazer merge vc PRECISA entender o que está por trás). Mas pra usar vc não precisa entender nada. Pra um desenvolvedor experiente, não entender pode ser uma frustração ou um problema. Mas não para a maior parte dos usuários, menos experientes.

Answer (score 8):

O motivo é bastante simples na verdade.

O ato de programar em si não consiste em "posicionar elementos", mas sim em definir funcionalidades. A maior parte do que precisa ser feito tem que ser descrito com alto nível de detalhamento.

Exemplo simples: É fácil posicionar um "botão" utilizando o DreamWeaver, mas é praticamente impossível fazê-lo funcionar sem digitar.

Quanto mais complexas as funcionalidades disponíveis (Independente de quantas você irá utilizar), mais difícil criar uma ferramenta com campos que atendam a todas as possibilidades.

Considerando a dificuldade de criar uma interface adequada, o número de linguagens, a velocidade de atualização das principais linguages e a quantidade de diferentes "níveis de abstração" que cada projeto utiliza, é praticamente impossível definir um padrão.

Se você faz algo do gênero, fica com algo na linha de um Visual Basic, ou pior, um Frontpage ou um Wix. A "simplicidade" da interface "custa" a possibilidade de expandir o programa, porque mesmo que você abra ambas as opções (Como no Dreamweaver) e mesmo que consiga replicar integralmente o funcionamento do "outro lado" (O Dreamweaver não replica perfeitamente um navegador, a título de curiosidade), o código gerado vai estar "poluído" porque é praticamente impossível para um programa executando tarefas visuais definir onde aquele código deveria estar, hierarquicamente falando, e qual a melhor forma de estruturá-lo.

Um último ponto importante de ser levantado é a "tradição". Programadores trabalham com texto, portanto se especializaram para trabalhar com texto. Teclados mecânicos, editores de texto poderosos (Como o VIM e o Emacs para os mais "hardcore" e o Sublime Text e o Atom.IO para os mais "modernos"). É difícil para um programa novo "compensar" para esses usuários mais antigos, e quando você precisa de funcionalidades mais avançadas acaba invariavelmente abandonando a IDE mais "complexa" em troca dessas funcionalidades. Isso não justifica que se abandonem as ideias, mas define um nível de exigência elevado, o que dificulta a entrada de IDEs com interface gráfica mais complexa.

Comment: Não concordo com "é praticamente impossível fazê-lo funcionar sem digitar". Isso pode ser verdade para o caso do DreamWeaver, mas não é uma verdade universal tendo em vista que há ferramentas que só produzem funcionalidade a partir de interação não textual.

Comment: Por outro lado, concordo bastante com a argumentação a respeito da "tradição". A tradição é realmente tão importante, a ponto de que nós praticamente só usamos um teclado por tradição da máquina de escrever (o posicionamento de teclas, QWERT, tem origem em evitar que os martelos da máquina de escrever se prendessem uns aos outros conforme textos em inglês eram digitados...) :)

Comment: O "praticamente impossível" se refere mais à dificuldade. A gente vem aprimorando editores de texto há décadas, enquanto uma IDE mais "gráfica" tem que começar mais "do zero". E aí surge outro problema: Complexidade. Se você arrasta Objetos e Arrays e Funções e Classes e JSON e por aí vai, primeiro, quantos botões existem na tela?, e segundo, o que acontece quando você precisa de uma funcionalidade que não existe? Aí ou você tem que ficar alternando do teclado pro mouse ou navegando Menus. O problema muda, não some. Nesse sentido que eu considero "quase impossível". :D

Answer (score 5):

Tive a mesma dúvida e após um tempo percebi que é preciso fazer três perguntas básicas
para decidir se eu devo usar Drag-and-Drop ou não.

**1 - Eu conheço o funcionamento deste código ?**

Quando você sabe como funciona o código copiado você não se preocupa com possíveis problemas, pois você já fez uma vez e viu que tudo da certo e se ocorrer algo vai conseguir dar manutenção.

**2 - A IDE que utilizo acompanha e implementa todas as novas regras e métodos da linguagem?**

Esta pergunta afeta intimamente o desempenho, Por exemplo o Netbeans, eu utilizo muito para programar em C++ e PHP, sempre lança atualizações juntamente com a empresa que mantém a linguagem.

**3 - Qual é o meu prazo pra desenvolver ?**

Se as respostas das perguntas 1 e 2 são positivas e seu tempo é pouco, use Drag-and-Drop, se você tem muito tempo
        Não faça POG, pense sempre no futuro.

Answer (score 4):

Isso ocorre pela:

- Facilidade de padronização da interface pelos designers, garantindo um mesmo design para todos os componentes usado na view/tela. Desse modo você só aninha os objetos e o designer implementa todo a parte estética dos componentes (Ex: botão, painel, pop-up e etc).
- Facilidade de manutenção e alteração da interface, pois basta alterar somente o design de um componente para que os outros componentes usados reflitam essa alteração/manutenção.

Acredito que drag-and-drop que você se refere é a parte visual do programa.

Para se construir uma aplicação web você possui centenas formas de estruturar seu programa, você pode fazer uma API para permitir acesso aos seu dados.

Usar essa API de dados em um programa Web com JSF fazendo o front-end (tela, view e etc), usar a mesma API em um Android ou IOS e assim por diante.

Por fim você sempre desenvolverá em camadas, tornando mais fácil a manutenção do seu código e diminuindo a interdependência entre as camadas.

Abraços.

Answer (score 4):

Eu acho que isto é um tanto quanto relativo, depende da aplicação, da tecnologia e das politicas da empresa. Veja o XCode por exemplo e o desenvolvimento para IOS, acredito que um bom trabalho é utilizando as ferramentas drag 'n drop, agora veja também o Dreamweaver, não sei se muita gente usa essas funcionalidades (em uma empresa que trabalhei não permitia o uso de drag'n drop do Dreamweaver por conta do codigo gerado), no Unity3D existe alguns plugins de dran'g drop muito utilizados e se eu não me engano com C# também é bastente utilizado as fucionalidades de drag'n drop. Eu particularmente não gosto de utilizar o drag'n drop pois prefiro mecher diretamente no codigo pois me dá mais intimidade e controle sobre o codigo e seu estilo.

Answer (score 4):

Atualmente as pessoas estão acostumadas às telas touch, perceba que o movimento é na verdade um deslize, onde é possível desbloquear a tela, alternar entre telas, etc. O movimento, deslize do dedo nos celulares e tablets não é um movimento completo, como acontece com Drag-and-drop, que é necessário tocar em ponto fixo, arrastar e soltar em outro ponto fixo. Portanto, deve-se observar que o conceito do Drag-and-drop pode ser adaptativo.